# Como chamar uma função no CakePHP 3.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3

Eu tenho uma view *add* que é um formulário de abertura de chamado help desk (referente a função *add*, claro), e tenho essa função *upload* que é para anexar arquivo a solicitação, que esta ligado com um *component*, mas eu nao quero deixa-los em *view* diferentes, pois se eu simplesmente enviar uma arquivo através da view *upload*, a imagem "se perde" e não liga ao chamado. Eu preciso que dentro da função *add* eu consiga chamar a função *upload*, pra juntar as views. Se eu chama-la através de ***$this->upload();*** , ou simplesmente fazer toda a verificação dentro de *add*, não encontra o *component*, me retornando um erro (que vou colocar abaixo), acredito que o conflito esteja no ***request->data***, mas não sei se existe uma forma de juntar da maneira que eu expliquei.

```
    public function add()
{

    $post = $this->Posts->newEntity();

    if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {
        $this->Posts->patchEntity($post, $this->request->data);
            $post->user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');



        if ($this->Posts->save($post)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Chamado enviado'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'listar']);
        }

        $this->Flash->error(__('Chamado nao enviado'));
    }


        $this->set(compact('post'));

}
```

---

```
public function upload()

{

    if ( !empty( $this->request->data ) ) {
        $this->Upload->send($this->request->data(['uploadfile']));
        return $this->redirect(['action'=>'add']);
    }

}
```

Component:

```
 public function send( $data )
{
    if ( !empty( $data) ) {
        if ( count( $data) > $this->max_files ) {
            throw new InternalErrorException("Error Processing Request. Max number files accepted is {$this->max_files}", 1);
        }

        foreach ($data as $file) {
            $filename = $file['name']; //linha 32, que da o erro abaixo;
            $file_tmp_name = $file['tmp_name']; //33
            $dir = WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.'Anexos';
            $allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg');
            if ( !in_array( substr( strrchr( $filename , '.') , 1 ) , $allowed) ) {
                throw new InternalErrorException("Error Processing Request.", 1);
            }elseif( is_uploaded_file( $file_tmp_name ) ){
                $filename = Text::uuid().'-'.$filename;

                $filedb = TableRegistry::get('Arquivos');
                $entity = $filedb->newEntity();
                $entity->filename = $filename;
                $filedb->save($entity);

                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name, $dir.DS.$filename);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

erro ao chamar upload();

```
Warning (2): Illegal string offset 'name' [APP/Controller\Component\UploadComponent.php, line 32]

Warning (2): Illegal string offset 'tmp_name' [APP/Controller\Component\UploadComponent.php, line 33]
```

view:

```
  <?php
        //essa é minha view add;
        echo $this->Form->input('id' );
        echo $this->Form->input('titulo');
        echo $this->Form->input('ip');
        echo $this->Form->input('mensagem');

    ?>
       //e essa é minha view upload, que eu gostaria de juntar com add;

      <?php echo $this->Form->create(null, ['type' => 'file']); ?>
      <label>Arquivos</label>
      <?php
      echo $this->Form->file('uploadfile.', ['multiple']);
      echo $this->Form->button('Anexar', ['action' => 'submit']);
      echo $this->Form->end();

       ?>
```

Vou upar essa pergunta pois ainda não consegui resolver, segue a imagem da minha *view*, de como eu quero fazer, mas se eu fizer assim (juntando as funções *add*) da o erro que mencionei acima. Eu posso colocar um link direcionando para anexar um arquivo em outra *view*, ai da certo, salva na pasta e no banco, mas o arquivo fica perdido, não fica atrelado a solicitação, e não é possível que o *cake* não me deixe fazer isso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: você verificou se dentro do $data esta vindo o parametro que vc quer ? digo o 'name' e o 'tmp_name' ?

Comment: dentro do $data esta vindo o parâmetro do "add", ai que esta a questão, como fazer com que o $data do "upload" busque 'nome' e 'tmp_name' estando dentro da função "add".